# in Immutablejs Map push into List

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am a beginner developer who is studying redux. I am using immutablejs to add object type data to the state. When you press the button on the react component, the test data (`Map ()`) is pushed to the `List()`. But there is a problem. When the button is pressed, the following type of data is input, and **when the page is refreshed, it is updated with normal data**. Why is this happening? I really appreciate your help.

[Before Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpTxx.png)

[After Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZEiG.png)

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Map, List } from 'immutable'

let token = localStorage.token
if (!token)
  token = localStorage.token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(-8)

let instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5001',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Authorization': token}
})

const GET_POST_PENDING = 'GET_POST_PENDING'
const GET_ALL_POST_SUCCESS = 'GET_ALL_POST_SUCCESS'
const CREATE_POST_SUCCESS = 'CREATE_POST_SUCCESS'
const GET_POST_FAILURE = 'GET_POST_FAILURE'


//actions

export const getPost = (postId) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: GET_POST_PENDING});

  return instance.get('/posts').then(
    response => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ALL_POST_SUCCESS,
        payload: response
      })
    }
  ).catch((error) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_POST_FAILURE,
      payload: error
    })
  })  
}


export const createPost = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: GET_POST_PENDING})

  return instance.post('/posts',{
    id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(-10),
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    title: 'test title',
    body:  'test body',
    category: 'redux',
    author: 'minwoo',
    deleted: false,
    voteScore: 1
  }).then(
    response => {
      console.log(response) //check data
      dispatch({
        type:CREATE_POST_SUCCESS,
        payload: response
      })
    }
  ).catch((error) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_POST_FAILURE,
      payload: error
    })
  })  
}

const initialState = Map({
    posts: List([]),
    comments: List([])
})
```

I know that the console should not be here. However, when I press the button, I want to check if the response data is transmitted correctly.

```
//reducer
export default handleActions({
    [GET_POST_PENDING]: (state, action) => {
      return state;
    },
    [GET_ALL_POST_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload.data)//for check data
      return state.set('posts', List([...action.payload.data]))
    },
    [CREATE_POST_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
      const posts = state.get('posts')
      return state.set('posts', posts.push(
          Map(action.payload.date)
      ))
    },
    [GET_POST_FAILURE]: (state, action) => {
      return state
    }
}, initialState)
```

The code below is the React component mentioned above.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { List } from 'immutable';

const PostList = ({posts, PostActions: {getPost}}) => {

  const postList = posts.map((post,i) => (
    <div key={i}>
      {post.title}
      <button>edit</button>
      <button>delete</button>
    </div>
  ))

  return (
    <div className="PostList">
      {postList}
    </div>
  )
}

PostList.proptypes = {
  posts: PropTypes.instanceOf(List),
  getPost: PropTypes.func
}

PostList.defaultProps = {
  posts:[],
  getPost: () => console.log('getPost is not defined')
}

export default PostList
```

Comment: Try changing `return state.set('posts', posts.push(
          Map(action.payload.date)
      ))` to `return state.set('posts', posts.push(
           action.payload.date
      ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` does not deeply convert your data, so when you pass an array of objects to `List` you will get a `List` object containing plain JS object.

Use `fromJS` instead of `List` in `GET_ALL_POST_SUCCESS`